# SQL SELECT only the rows not containing ID used in related table

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables with simple relation. One table is list of sales. The second table is list of products. Relation is that in the Sales table is a Product ID that points to the given product.

I need to retrieve the details on the products that were never sold.

Here are links to the two tables:
[Table with Products](http://imageshack.us/a/img853/8143/products2.jpg) & [Table with Sales](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/6355/exampletablesales2.jpg)

If you don't want to click it, the tables look like this:

```
**SALES**

id
sale_id
product_id
quantity

**PRODUCTS**

id
name
category_id
stock
brand_id
price
color
warranty
```

So far I have this:

```
SELECT products.id 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN sale_products ON sale_products.product_id = products.id 
WHERE products.id NOT IN (sale_products.product_id) 
GROUP BY products.id
```

But this doesn't retrieve anything, although if I take out the NOT then I get all the 17 IDs of the 17 sold items...

So I'd say it either has to be changed around or done with completely different approach..

Any help is much appreciated and welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT products.id 
    FROM products 
    LEFT JOIN sale_products ON sale_products.product_id = products.id 
    WHERE sales_products.product_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY products.id
```

You are asking for all products and for each product, either get a sales record or if no sales record found, return NULL for each column in the sales_product table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    PRODUCTS P
WHERE 
    P.ID NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            PRODUCT_ID 
        FROM 
            SALES
    )
```